# Spring Cloud: How to read hystrix metrics data programmatically?

Tags: hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

My application uses hystrix as circuit breaker. I want to export hystrix metrics data to InfluxDB(or other storage service). I didn't find any docuemnts taking about how to read these data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog very useful regarding this subject.  http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2015/02/storing-months-of-historical-metrics.html  .
  This talks about exporting data to graphite, I am sure it can be extended to InfluxDB as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to custom write hystrix metrics data, you can see [here](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1298)